# PDF not rendering in Website using PDF.JS

Tags: pdf, html5-canvas, pdf.js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/gh-pages/build/pdf.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var url =    'https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1AFArMkWop2N0xVN3VtdURxM2RhamduR3h3c2EwN1BmX0NJ/aditya_res    ume.pdf';

'use strict';

PDFJS.getDocument(url).then(function(pdf) 
{

   pdf.getPage(1).then(function(page) 
{
 var scale = 1.5;
 var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);


 var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas');
 var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
 canvas.height = viewport.height;
 canvas.width = viewport.width;


   var renderContext = 
   {
    canvasContext: context,
    viewport: viewport
   };


 page.render(renderContext);
});
```

Now this is my code to render a page in my webpage but its not rendering anything. what is wrong with this.Please point me in right direction.

Should i disable PDFJs.worker? I have read abt it sme where. What is the use of PDFJS worker??

Comment: Are the spaces in your URL a typo?

Comment: yes.Its a typo. Its not displaying anything on my website

Comment: browsers security model does not allow cross-domain worker loading, so yes you have to disable worker (which is sucks since you don't want to any processing on main thread).

Comment: best if you will place build/pdf.js and build/pdf.worker.js near your html page

Comment: Ok thanks for the advise. So should I disable worker or just place it near my html page??? Then what about URL. URL doesn't have this issue? Can we specify any URL without having any of these problems?